# Minimum distance of curve from origin

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, parametric, maxima-minima

I have a parabola $(y+5)^2 = 4x$ and I need to find its minimum distance from origin. Scientific calculators aren't allowed. 
I have tried :

1) Substituting parametric coordinates $(r\cos Q, r\sin Q)$ but the expression of $r$ in $Q$ obtained after differenciation doesn't give roots which can be calculated by hand.

2) Used point form of tangent for $(x_1,y_1)$ on parabola and made line joining origin and $(x_1,y_1)$ perpendicular but it forms a cubic equation which again can't be solved by hand.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

The solution DO involves solving a cubic equation, which, by the way, CAN be solved by hand with Cardano's method.

Comment: Alternatively you could approximate it with 1 or 2 newton raphson iterations. With a suitable starting point like y = -3. I think the equation we are trying to solve is $(y + 5) ^ 3 + 8y = 0$

Comment: I didn't know about cardano's method earlier. Thanks